# How do I make VSCode's type-checker see a JS class and a TS class as the same thing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, typechecking

I set up a class in a TS file for type-checking a class by the same name in a JS file. As things are now on my end, VSCode's type-checker sees the classes as completely separate. How do I make it so that as I work on the JS version, the type-checker uses the TS version as reference to spot any mistakes?

Example code:

```
// TS file
declare namespace Namespace1
{
    declare namespace Namespace2
    {
        declare class Foo
        {
            _num1: number;
            get num1(): number;
            bar(): number;
        }
    }
}

// JS file
'use strict';

// I'd have another module assign this to the correct namespace
class Foo
{
    get num1() { return this._num1; } // Type-checker says _num1 doesn't exist in this class
    bar()
    {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example of this?

Comment: @MattBierner Added an example